# Moving from bitbucket to self-hosted gitlab, LFS is 0 bytes

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab, bitbucket, git-lfs

I have imported my bitbucket repo into a self-hosted gitlab project. Everything seemed to work fine, but when I check the project info, the project is only 94mb and LFS is 0 bytes. In bitbucket when I check LFS info, there's about 800mb of data.

Seems the import does not include LFS? What is the easiest way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have gitlab set up to work with LFS.  Info here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/workflow/lfs/manage_large_binaries_with_git_lfs.html

Whether there's a way to include LFS in the import, I don't know; but since you've already done the import of the core repo, it may be as well not to worry about that.

You can use a local repo as a go-between to get all the LFS objects into gitlab.  This may be time consuming due to the volume of data involved.  In a clone of the original repo, you would do a `git lfs fetch --all` (which is documented as being "primarily for backup *or migration* purposes").

Then you would update your local repo's remotes (and, important to remember if it's set separately, LFS URL) to refer to the new repo, and do a `git lfs push --all`